# How to get every specific days of week within given date range in PHP?

Tags: php, date, schedule, dayofweek

This give me every monday date in date range.

**Question: How to get every monday and friday of week?**

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date . ' + 1 MONTH'));

for(
    $i = strtotime('Monday', strtotime($start_date)); 
    $i <= strtotime($end_date); 
    $i = strtotime('+1 WEEK', $i)
) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', $i). '<br>';
}
```

**My Update:**

```
$my_dates = [];
for(
    $i = strtotime($start_date); 
    $i <= strtotime($end_date); 
    $i = strtotime('+1 DAY', $i)
) {
    if(in_array(date('N', $i), array(1, 5))) {
        $my_dates[] = date('Y-m-d', $i);
    }
}

var_dump($my_dates);
```

Comment: There's only so many seconds between Monday and Friday.

Comment: You could loop over all the days and compare the value of `date("N")` (1 is Monday)

Comment: http://codepad.org/eRWSC5MU

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @Uchiha every monday/friday date in range of dates (start/end_date)

Comment: http://codepad.org/JwuCgslC

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at library called [When](https://github.com/tplaner/When), it's *"Date / Calendar recursion library for PHP 5.3+"*.

Let's say MF schedule for next month:

```
$now = new DateTime('NOW');
$till = clone $now;
$till->modify('+1 month');

$r = new When();
$r->startDate($now)
  ->freq("weekly")
  ->until($till)
  ->byday(array('MO', 'FR'))
  ->generateOccurrences();

$occurrences = $r->occurrences;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong than you can simply use `for` loop like as

```
$start = "2015-09-01";
$end = date('Y-m-d',  strtotime("$start +1 months"));
$period = floor((strtotime($end) - strtotime($start))/(24*60*60));

for($i = 0; $i < $period; $i++){
    if(in_array(date('l',strtotime("$start +$i day")),["Monday","Friday"]))
        echo date('l d M, Y',strtotime("$start +$i day"))."\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Friday 04 Sep, 2015
Monday 07 Sep, 2015
Friday 11 Sep, 2015
Monday 14 Sep, 2015
Friday 18 Sep, 2015
Monday 21 Sep, 2015
Friday 25 Sep, 2015
Monday 28 Sep, 2015
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/L2UMW)